# sum column table(not in db)

Tags: php

my table calculates total without tax from total inclusive of tax the snippet of my page is available below
getting the total of the inclusive column is easy with the SUM(column) query
i however want to calculate sum total(without tax ) which is not in the db
for this column i am using

```
<?php
$inclusive=$row_returns['Total'];
$total=$inclusive*0.86;
echo $total;
?>
```

and for the total inclusive of tax i am using`{returns.Inclusive}`
where its total is obviously

```
<?php     
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(Inclusive) AS tot FROM returns');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['tot'];
echo $sum;
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but you are storing the total including taxes in the database. By that total you want to substract the tax to present the net summary? What if there are different taxes?

Comment: i am dealing with one kinf of tax (value added tax which is 16% of all commodities sold)

Comment: hence total inclusive of tax is 116% so that to get total without is[(total inclusive of tax)*116/100--->116/100=0.86

Comment: This formula is way off in the long run. I'll post an answer with the formula and how to calculate your net summary.

Comment: @ Daniel is the a way i can add a snippet of the table to this post?still new here.

Comment: Click the `edit` link under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all; Calculating the net you use the formula `total_included / rate`.

Now to present the net you calculate your totals using;

```
SELECT SUM(Included) AS gross, SUM(Included / 1.16) AS net
```

Hope I get your question.

Comment: In this way you will calculate the net directly, which will spare you time and debugging issues later on. Efficiency at its best. To access the net you will only need to output the result through `$row['net']` (excluding tax) and `$row['gross']` (including tax).

Comment: cool...worked but in case i need this in future
how do you get sum of html table column with figures already in
 on a repeated table

Comment: Calculations should always be done before output. If you are talking about javascript and html I suggest you open a new question on how to parse the table.